Connecting MySQL 9.0.1 with Spring Boot 3.3.4 on MacOs 14
I wanted to set up my very first Spring Boot project, however I cannot figure out how to correctly connect the MySQL database to it.
When I add the following, the correct columns of the database are created (I check them with MySQL workbench) but the application terminates with
“Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader”
My Pom.xml has this:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version> <!-- Updated version -->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


and my application.properties this:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Adding
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
Does not work. When I do, it is marked red and says “cannot resolve class or package MySQL”
Additional Details:
I’m using MySQL 9.0.1 which I downloaded with homebrew (on the website it says this version is stable).
I’m working on MacOS 14.4.1
So I tried everything I could find on the Internet but nothing helped. I don’t understand what’s the issue if creating the columns is successful.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Try instead the following dependency: <dependency><groupId>com.mysql</groupId><artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId><scope>runtime</scope></dependency>

@g00se I tried this and still get "Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders" when running it.

How are you running it?

@g00se I'm using IntelliJ and its run/play button.

Change to directory of pom.xml and try mvn spring-boot:run

Did you added the mysql dependency from the https://start.spring.io/ or after searching in the google and taking from maven repository.
Try selecting the Mysql from https://start.spring.io/

@g00se Wow this seems to work. Thank you so much! I don't understand why the regular way did not work though.

@RohithV I tried out both and I always got the same error sadly.

@g00se Wow this seems to work. Thank you so much! Always be build-system-led as against IDE-led. Some IDEs mangle the major build systems (Gradle, Maven) and/or insert conflicting configurations of their own.
